# jquery Serialize Method to be implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

1. users often bookmark a search page after they have selected some facets to refine their search query.  The refinements panel needs to be able to serialize the selected facets for inclusion in the URL each time a facet is selected or unselected.

http://jsfiddle.net/sk7pqf5c/

The serialization Method should be:

```
?refine=panelId:facet1id...
```

Comment: So what is your issue exactly? Do you not know how to create the string or how to rip it apart.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not sure, I'm a bit lost. would u be able to help?

Comment: I do not know what your problem is to help you...

Comment: @epascarello I've only have this informations :-(

Comment: So basically you do not know how to do your homework/job interview test? You need to build the string using loops and you need to rip it apart using loops and split.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, its an implementation, but not sure i'm able to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the data representing what has been selected like this:

```
$('#getSelection').click(function(){
    var selection = $('.panel').map(function(_,e){
        var $e = $(e);
        return {
            panelId: $e.data('id'),
            selectedFacets: $e.find('input:checkbox:checked').map( function(_,i){
                return i.id;
            }).get()
        };
    }).get();
    console.log(selection)
});
```

That assumes a button with the id `getSelection`, and this code creates an array of objects with the following:

> [Object { panelId="size", selectedFacets=[1]}, Object { panelId="base_colour", selectedFacets=[1]}, Object { panelId="brand", selectedFacets=[1]}]

In that example, each `selectedFacets` property is an array of the `id` attribute from the checkboxes.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/sk7pqf5c/4/

From there you just need to turn that array in to a string and pass it wherever you like on a quesrystring. Going the other way, you need to parse that string, turn it back into an array similar to what is produced above, and use it to pre-select the checkboxes on screen.

Comment: @epascarello - Im sorry, do you *know* this is homework? Plus this is far from the final solution, and just pushes the OP in the right direction. Plus I have a [history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254474/using-javascript-for-arrays-and-loops/26254692#26254692) of giving people just the help they need without too much in the case of Homework. So, basically what Im saying is butt out! with respect.